# How can I print out more than one random result without possible duplicates in any print statements

Tags: python, random, duplicates

I am doing a basic random number generator which prints out the fist 6 numbers in a range up to 45 which works fine but I need it to print out a second time with 2 numbers up to 45, these two numbers can not be the same as any of the 6 numbers either.

```
enter code here
import random

nums = range(1, 45)
supps = range(1,45)

print(random.sample(nums,6))
print(random.sample(supps,2))
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can samply generate 8 random numbers and put them in array, then print the first 6 numbers and 2 last numbers :

```
import random

nums = range(1, 45)
random_nums = random.sample(nums,8)
print('First six numbers : ',random_nums[:6],'Last two numbers : ',random_nums[6:])
```

*NB : idk if you intend to use the "range" function in that way or you declared it somewhere else, because at that way it wont work, do this instead :*

```
nums = []
for i in range(1,46):
    nums.append(i)
```

Comment: Brilliant, that will do it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Karam, what's the problem with using `range` objects?  the docs for `random.sample` explicitly point this out as a recommended idiom

Comment: @Paora if it's good dont forget to mark the answer

Comment: @SamMason he used 2 range objects while he could do it only with one and still get distinct numbers

Comment: you can iterate over the same `range` object an arbitrary number of times, no need to copy into a `list`

Comment: @SamMason the list had one purpose is to save the elements for futur uses on the code, he wants to use the elements so you cant juste make the process again and again